# How to select camera by index when running VLC from cmd?

Tags: command-line, vlc-media-player, camera, selection

When I start VLC from cmd how is it possible to select a camera for a [DirectShow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectShow) source by index (for example I have camera "A" and camera "B" so I would say 0 for "A" and 1 for "B")?

I do not know the device name, and I do not know the camera name - only it's index (0, 1...).

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is to write or use some external application that can do the enumeration and mapping for you, then pass in the device name.  Or you could put in a feature request for it...

You can select the pin number (capture device tab, advanced options)